Subjunctives and continuous
When we use the word "suggest" to indeed suggest something we are only allowed you use (after that word) present or past simple or subjunctive. It depends if you're from USA or UK.

I suggest you eat now

I suggest you are eating now


Both are correct, but only 1 suggests something and 2 says what I think that someone is doing. Now, to my question. I'd like to suggest someone that they should be eating before their mom comes to see them.

I suggest you are eating when she comes.

Does my 3 version make sense? I'm confused because we don't use the continuous tenses with "suggest" when we suggest something not just think what someone does yet it is the only way to indicate something happens before another event.

Why do so many example sentences on ELL end with "when she comes" ?  Is there a universally used introduction to  English which uses that phrase in its examples?

I suggest that I suggest you are eating when she comes is not a credible thing to say in English. It's a ridiculously contrived utterance anyway, but at least I suggest [that] you [should] be eating when she comes is syntactically and semantically valid (the are version is neither).

@TimR I suspect some of them are sock puppet accounts of a very fixated user

Are you sure that #2 is a valid use anywhere? It's not, to my knowledge. It's hard to separate "I suggest" from its modal sense (i.e. "I recommend"), at least in this example about "you" and eating. If you mean the meaning "I tentatively assert," it might be possible in some other example, like "I suggest that the flooding in the basement is due to the grade of the soil," where we're farther away from a "recommendation" situation. This really is the problem with #3, and why it needs to be "eat" rather than "are eating." AFAIK there's no US/UK difference on this.

In American English, I'd prefer the present subjunctive

I suggest you be [adjectival phrase]

although this leads to the somewhat unusual

I suggest you be eating when she comes.

This has a very folksy vibe to it that I can't quite explain. More than that, I'd prefer

I suggest that you be [adjectival phrase]


I suggest that you be eating when she comes.


I agree with you on this but I'm not sure what you mean by the folksy vibe.

No subjunctive.  Just "use your words"

You should start eating before she arrives.

If subjunctive can be avoided then they should be avoided.  Use modals instead.


I suggest you are showing remorse when the judge questions you at the sentencing hearing.

That is not idiomatic in American English.  We would not use the continuous there 99% of the time, and certainly not with are.
We'd say

I suggest you show remorse.

But it's not absolutely impossible, though we would use be:

I suggest you be sitting not standing when sewing on a button.

though that would be rare. Most of the time it would be:

I suggest you be seated when ...

or

I suggest you sit when ...


"I suggest you sit when he visits you" implies that siting happens at the same time or after him visiting. I want to indicate it starts before

I suggest you be seated when he arrives.  comes, visits do not express the point in time needed for your meaning.  Or you could say I suggest you be already seated when he comes  if you want to make that meaning perfectly clear.  already is the better way as it does not rely solely on the verb to establish the desired meaning.

would you consider my 2 example correct? "Suggest"used as that's what i think is going on not proposing anything?

It's hard to imagine  in what circumstances you would use that sentence. It could be correct with other verbs, for example "I suggest [that] you are thinking of a different book" (when you say something that isn't true of the book I am talking about).

@Adam  What is your intended meaning with suggest in the rather opaque #2, I suggest you are eating now.  ?   Are you advising the person to eat something because it will be a long hike, or are you disagreeing with them, they saying they're watching a movie but you saying they seem more interested in their popcorn?  The sentence is borderline nonsense until you provide some context.
